# I Loved a man but he passed away he was unmarried I want to be with him in jannah is it possible?...is it ok to stay unmarried according to islam?

Tags: nikah, allah, jannah, love

I loved a man but he passed away He was unmarried and He had righteous character and I fell for him because of that, I do not plan on getting married in this life and I've been praying to Allah, wishing to be with the man I love in the after life. Will I be able to be his wife if I pray and ask Allah and remain unmarried and protect my chaste/purity?
And suggest me some surahs and duas for my question;_;